# Defining Loss function in pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch, loss-function

I have to define a huber loss function which is this:[image]

This is my code

```
def huber(a, b): 
   res = (((a-b)[abs(a-b) < 1]) ** 2 / 2).sum()
   res += ((abs(a-b)[abs(a-b) >= 1]) - 0.5).sum()
   res = res / torch.numel(a)
   return res
```

'''

yet, it is not working properly. Do you have any idea what is wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by `it is not working properly`? Is it mathematical correctness or some issue in `pytorch`?

Answer (score 1):

Huber loss function already exists in PyTorch under the name of `torch.nn.SmoothL1Loss`.

Follow this link https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.SmoothL1Loss.html for more!